# From where Paul received the tradition of Lord Supper in - I Corinthians 11:23?

Tags: paul

In 1 Corinthians 11:23 Paul says

> For I received from the Lord what I also handed on to you

This implies that Paul received the tradition of Lord Supper (1 Corinthians 11:24-25) from Jesus Christ which is hardly possible as the encounter with Jesus Christ while on the way of Damascus in Luke 9:1-18 does not contain any thing of Lord Supper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is abundantly clear from Paul's epistles that he received a great deal from the Lord. He communicates doctrine that the other apostles, who were physically with Jesus for a period of three years, do not communicate. He says himself in Galatians that when he met the other apostles, in conference, they 'added nothing to me'.

Rather than meet with anyone else after his experience on the Damascus road, he departed into the desert. Paul received a great deal, quite evidently, directly from the Lord. His brief encounter *which is recorded* is obviously just *one instance* of the communication that developed between Jesus Christ and himself.

Comment: Excellent comment Nigel J +1.  Paul was a prophet that received revelations from God and so had a direct source.